# How to translate this method from Objective-C to Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm trying to translate [this class](https://gist.github.com/adib/5341936) from Objective-C to Swift. I'm almost done except for this method:

```
-(void) handleCookiesInRequest:(NSMutableURLRequest*) request
    {
    NSURL* url = request.URL;
    NSArray* cookies = [self cookiesForURL:url];
    NSDictionary* headers = [NSHTTPCookie requestHeaderFieldsWithCookies:cookies];

    NSUInteger count = [headers count];
    __unsafe_unretained id keys[count], values[count];
    [headers getObjects:values andKeys:keys];

    for (NSUInteger i=0;i<count;i++) {
        [request setValue:values[i] forHTTPHeaderField:keys[i]];
    }
}
```

My attempt:

```
func handleCookiesInRequest(request: NSMutableURLRequest) {
    var url = request.URL
    var cookies = self.cookiesForURL(url!)
    var headers = NSHTTPCookie.requestHeaderFieldsWithCookies(cookies)

    var count = headers.count
    for i in 0...count {
        request.setValue(value: headers.values[i], forHTTPHeaderField: headers.keys[i])
    }
}
```

I get an error in the line that set value saying

```
CustomHTTPCookieStorage.swift:88:21: Type '(value: $T8, forHTTPHeaderField: $T21)' does not conform to protocol '_SignedIntegerType'
```

Can you help me?

Comment: What is the value of `value`?

Comment: Sorry. I did paste a wrong method. I've just updated it. Could you re check?

Comment: This is the part i don't understand: __unsafe_unretained id keys[count], values[count];

Comment: The original author was jumping through hoops to pull out the keys and values into separate arrays and then iterated over both. That was overcomplicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSHTTPCookie.requestHeaderFieldsWithCookies()` returns a dictionary, not an array. You meant this:

```
for (key, value) in headers {
    request.setValue(value as? String, forHTTPHeaderField: key as! String)
}
```

You can make this a bit safer this way:

```
if let headers = NSHTTPCookie.requestHeaderFieldsWithCookies(cookies) as? [String:String] {
    for (key, value) in headers {
        request.setValue(value, forHTTPHeaderField: key)
    }
}
```

Of course, if you haven't set any headers yet, this can all be replaced with:

```
request.allHTTPHeaderFields = NSHTTPCookie.requestHeaderFieldsWithCookies(cookies)
```

But this will blow away any preset headers, so the semantics are a little different.

Comment: Great! Thanks! The comment it my question with the explanation was also useful.